# Save ID two columns Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to save the ID of a new Sale(); in `$sale->voucher_series`, how can I achieve this?

```
$sale = new Sale();
$sale->customerid = $request->customerid;
$sale->userid = \Auth::user()->id;
$sale->proof_type = $request->proof_type;
$sale->voucher_series = $request->saleId;
$sale->date_time = $mytime->toDateString();
$sale->total = $request->total;
$sale->status = 'Registered';
$sale->save();
```

Comment: You want to save the records primary key in another column on the same record? That doesn't make any sense...

Comment: if exactly that, what I want is for the primary key to be my voucher string

Comment: If the voucher string is the same as the primary key, just use the primary key.

Comment: But is there any way to make it duplicate in voucher series

Comment: I could already solve it in another way. Thank you very much, I appreciate your attention. Take care

Comment: add another help topic, hope you can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your voucher_series column is nullable field then it will work.

```
$sale = new Sale (); 
$sale->customerid = $request->customerid;
$sale->userid = \Auth :: user()->id;
$sale->proof_type = $request->proof_type;
$sale->date_time = $mytime->toDateString ();
$sale->total = $request->total;
$sale->status = 'Registered';
$sale->save();


$sale->voucher_series = $sale->id;
```

Comment: I could already solve it in another way. Thank you very much, I appreciate your attention. Take care

Comment: add another help topic, hope you can help me